# How to use ffpmpeg to concatenate 2 .m4v files and keep the subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg

Currently I use an ffmpeg command like this:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy output
```

The list.txt file has something like:

```
file 'File1-SideA.m4v'
file 'File2-SideB.m4v'
```

However, I lose the subtitles from the input file.  How do I modify my command to keep them?

Comment: Add `-map 0`...

Comment: Hmm. Now I get  <br>
    [ipod @ 0x7fdd4d841600] Tag text incompatible with output codec id '100359' ([0][0][0][0]) 
    Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?):
    Invalid data found when processing input Error initializing output stream 0:4

Comment: I tried this option again on a different file and this time it worked

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -map 0 -c copy ‘The Ten Commandments (1956).mp4’